# Prevent user creating new users with specific roles

Tags: multisite, users, user-roles, capabilities, user-registration

On a multisite installation I have created some custom roles. Some of them have the capabilities to create new users.

I want to allow users to create new users only with allowed roles.

One step is to use the `editable_roles` filter to remove roles from the dropdown but this doesn't prevent the user from modifying the select value and create a user with "not allowed" role.

Comment: Do you use the free or pro version? Can I suggest contacting the plugin owner? I had a problem with his plugin (pro version) and couldn't achieved something similar. He answered fast and solved my problem.

Comment: I also tried without the plugin and didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

> One step is to use the `editable_roles` filter to remove roles from the dropdown but this doesn't prevent the user from modifying the select value and create a user with "not allowed" role.

Yes it does. This filter is not just for the dropdown. Modifying [`editable_roles`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/editable_roles/) does in fact prevent users from assigning a role they're not allowed to.

This is because [`edit_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/edit_user/) (the function used for adding new users) calls [`get_editable_roles()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_editable_roles/) as well and bails when one is not allowed to give users that role.

Here's a simple example of what you can do:

```
/**
 * Removes Administrator from roles list if user isn't an admin themselves.
 *
 * This way, only admins can make new admins.
 *
 * @param array $all_roles List of roles.
 * @return array Modified list of roles.
 */
function wpse_293133_filter_editable_roles( $all_roles ) {
  if ( ! is_super_admin( get_current_user_id() ) ) {
    unset( $all_roles['administrator'] );
  }

  return $all_roles;
}

add_filter( 'editable_roles', 'wpse_293133_filter_editable_roles' );
```

Comment: @swisspidy thank you for your answer but I already tried that and it worked as I described. I took another test on a clean WP installation. I created two roles with the same capabilities using the User Role Editor plugin. I removed the "roleb" using `editable_roles`. The "roleb" doesn't appear in the dropdown but I changed the value of another role in the DOM using the inspector to "roleb". User successfully created with "roleb".

Comment: I can confirm that is working on single installations but not on Multisite.